# Executing a Python program in Django with every new entry is posted in REST API

Tags: python, django, flutter, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm fairly new to Django. I am creating an application where I am posting images from flutter application to Django REST API. I need to run a python script with the input as the image that gets posted in the API.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is a job management system (e.g. Slurm, Torque, and Oracle Grid Engine) as you can create and submit a job with every uploaded image and send the response back to the user and the job management system will process independently from the request. Celery can also work if the job won't take much time.

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation that scales well:

- Upload the images in a directory `uploaded`
- Have your script run as a daemon (controlled by systemd) looking for new files in directory `uploaded`
- whenever it finds a new file, it moves `mv` it to a directory `working` (that way, you can run multiple instances of your script in parallel to scale up)
- once your script us done with the image, it moves it to a directory `finished` (or where-ever you need the finished images).

That setup is very simple, and works on both a small one-machine setups with low traffic, as well as on multi-machine setups with dedicated storage and multiple worker machines that handle the image transform jobs.

It also decouples your image processing from your web backend.